# Convert legacy OpenGL script to a newer one

Tags: grid, surface-shader

I have a [script](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5294893/A-Csharp-3D-Surface-Plot-Control) drawing 3D chart, three axes and a surface. Unfortunately, it was implemented using old OpenGL approach with `Begin` and `End`. This makes it extremely inefficient and it gets very slow if I try to use more than 100 points per dimension. I would like to rewrite it using array buffers, possibly shaders, but all tutorials are focusing on drawing primitives.

**Question**

I was looking for a tutorial explaining how to draw `continuous surface` and `lines` or `grids` using modern OpenGL. If there is no tutorial explaining this explicitly, could somebody provide a sample array or shader and explain how OpenGL maps vertices to a surface. Specifically, in the old script, it has an array of vertices and array of colors

[image]

Meanwhile, the new approach, e.g. demonstrated in Silk.NET framework shows continuous array buffers with 5 dimensions - X, Y, Z, U, V.

[image]

**Explicit references to the code**

1. Old: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5294893/A-Csharp-3D-Surface-Plot-Control
2. New: https://github.com/dotnet/Silk.NET/blob/main/examples/CSharp/OpenGL%20Tutorials/Tutorial%202.1%20-%20Co-ordinate%20Systems/Program.cs

**Excerpt from the code**

Old:

```
void DrawShadedSurface(VertexStore vertices)
{
  float axisScaling = 0.25f * _axisScaling;

  GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Triangles);
  for (int index = 0; index < vertices.Vertices.Length; index += 5)
  {
    float midpointX = (axisScaling * (vertices.Vertices[index].X + vertices.Vertices[index + 1].X + vertices.Vertices[index + 2].X + vertices.Vertices[index + 3].X));
    float midpointY = (axisScaling * (vertices.Vertices[index].Y + vertices.Vertices[index + 1].Y + vertices.Vertices[index + 2].Y + vertices.Vertices[index + 3].Y));
    float midpointZ = (axisScaling * (vertices.Vertices[index].Z + vertices.Vertices[index + 1].Z + vertices.Vertices[index + 2].Z + vertices.Vertices[index + 3].Z));

    float midpointR = 0.25f * (vertices.Vertices[index].Colour.R + vertices.Vertices[index + 1].Colour.R + vertices.Vertices[index + 2].Colour.R + vertices.Vertices[index + 3].Colour.R);
    float midpointG = 0.25f * (vertices.Vertices[index].Colour.G + vertices.Vertices[index + 1].Colour.G + vertices.Vertices[index + 2].Colour.G + vertices.Vertices[index + 3].Colour.G);
    float midpointB = 0.25f * (vertices.Vertices[index].Colour.B + vertices.Vertices[index + 1].Colour.B + vertices.Vertices[index + 2].Colour.B + vertices.Vertices[index + 3].Colour.B);

    for (int offset = 0; offset < 4; ++offset)
    {
      int indexStart = index + offset;

      GL.Color4(midpointR, midpointG, midpointB, 1f);
      GL.Vertex3(midpointX, midpointY, midpointZ * ZScale);
    }
  }

  GL.End();
}
```

New

```
private static IWindow window;
private static GL Gl;

private const int Width = 800;
private const int Height = 700;

private static BufferObject<float> Vbo;
private static BufferObject<uint> Ebo;
private static VertexArrayObject<float, uint> Vao;
private static Texture Texture;
private static Shader Shader;

//Setup the camera's location, and relative up and right directions
private static Vector3 CameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
private static Vector3 CameraTarget = Vector3.Zero;
private static Vector3 CameraDirection = Vector3.Normalize(CameraPosition - CameraTarget);
private static Vector3 CameraRight = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(Vector3.UnitY, CameraDirection));
private static Vector3 CameraUp = Vector3.Cross(CameraDirection, CameraRight);

private static readonly float[] Vertices =
{
  //X    Y      Z     U   V
  -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

  -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

   0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

  -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

  -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
  -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
};

private static readonly uint[] Indices =
{
  0, 1, 3,
  1, 2, 3
};

private static void OnLoad()
{
  Gl = GL.GetApi(window);

  Ebo = new BufferObject<uint>(Gl, Indices, BufferTargetARB.ElementArrayBuffer);
  Vbo = new BufferObject<float>(Gl, Vertices, BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer);
  Vao = new VertexArrayObject<float, uint>(Gl, Vbo, Ebo);

  Vao.VertexAttributePointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, 5, 0);
  Vao.VertexAttributePointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, 5, 3);

  Shader = new Shader(Gl, "shader.vert", "shader.frag");
}

private static unsafe void OnRender(double obj)
{
  Gl.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
  Gl.Clear((uint) (ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit));

  Vao.Bind();
  Shader.Use();
  Shader.SetUniform("uTexture0", 0);

  //Use elapsed time to convert to radians to allow our cube to rotate over time
  var difference = (float) (window.Time * 100);

  var model = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(difference)) * Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(difference));
  var view = Matrix4x4.CreateLookAt(CameraPosition, CameraTarget, CameraUp);
  var projection = Matrix4x4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(45.0f), Width / Height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

  Shader.SetUniform("uModel", model);
  Shader.SetUniform("uView", view);
  Shader.SetUniform("uProjection", projection);

  //We're drawing with just vertices and no indicies, and it takes 36 verticies to have a six-sided textured cube
  Gl.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 36);
}
```

Shader.frag

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 fUv;

uniform sampler2D uTexture0;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(uTexture0, fUv);
}
```

Shader.vert

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vUv;

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uView;
uniform mat4 uProjection;

out vec2 fUv;

void main()
{
    //Multiplying our uniform with the vertex position, the multiplication order here does matter.
    gl_Position = uProjection * uView * uModel * vec4(vPos, 1.0);
    fUv = vUv;
}
```